# This is about matrix $m \times n$ as vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I got a question from my book, to prove $m \times n$ matrices with standard operation is a vector space. I know that I must prove 10 axioms of vector space, and I confuse in the inverse, that is $u + (-u) = 0$. I assume if we talk about matrix then, the inverse must change to $AA^{-1} = I$? But, I think not every $m \times n$ matrix has inverse, right? So, it is not a vector space.

Any help appreciate.

Comment: But the addition on matrices is the usual addition...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "standard operation" that you have mentioned in your question is simply matrix addition,not multiplication.

Then it has no problem because $A+(-A)=0$
The "inverse" of $A$ here negative of A i.e $-A$ and the "identity" is the zero matrix.

Comment: I assume wrong, I get it now

Answer (score 2):

The inverse is for matrix addition: $A+(-A)=0$ the zero matrix which is identity with respect to addition.

If you take square matrices (of the same order) and matrix multiplication, you are talking about an $\mathbb{F}$-algebra.

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

The set of $m × n$ matrices is a vector space, with the usual addition and
scalar multiplication of matrices. The ‘zero vector’ in this vector space is the zero
$m × n$ matrix with all entries equal to $0$.

Comment: so, I assume wrong by the way. I got it now.